# Django dont show pdf from database

Tags: html, django, pdf

Learning Django and want show pdf documents from database on html page. But I have error: Unable to connect to site, ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

models.py

```py
class Certificate(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='pdf')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural='09. Certificates'
```

views.py

```py
def certificates(request):
    certificates = Certificate.objects.filter(status=True).order_by('-id')
    return render(request, 'certificates.html', {'certificates': certificates})
```

certificates.html

```html
{% block content %}
<main class="container my-4">
    <h3 class="my-4 border-bottom pb-1">Сертификаты</h3>
    <div class="row">
        {% for certificate in certificates %}
        <html>
          <div class="card shadow">
            <h1>{{certificate.title}}</h1>
            <iframe src="//media/{{certificate.pdf}}" width="100%" height="100%">
            </iframe>
          </div>
        </html>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

I took information in parts through Google, maybe I missed the important setting, but I can't find a solution? Site is running locally on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I tried to solve problem please check with below code your side

### models.py

```py
class Certificate(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='pdf')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

### views.py

```py
def View1(request):
    all_data= Certificate.objects.filter(status=True).order_by('-id')
    context = {'data':all_data}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

### settings.py (add this line at last)

```py
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

### Html code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {% for i in data %}
        <div class="col p-3">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{i.title}}</h5>
            <iframe src="{{i.pdf.url}}" style=" width:600px; height:400px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>

        </div>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
</div>
```

### browser Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks, a lot! I met "X_FRAME_OPTIONS" in articles, but didn't understand how it works.

Comment: for a better understanding visit the link here...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: in first paragraph mentioned